# why does npm info <package> NOT match the github package.json file?

Tags: node.js, github, version-control, npm, version

I'm trying to install a number of js packages - via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) - and match their dependencies
However there are (significant) differences between:

- what is shown by `npm info <package>`
- what I see in the github `package.json` file (for the same version)

---

**Example:**
- `npm info angular-ui-calendar@1.0.2` shows no dependencies

```
{ name: 'angular-ui-calendar',
  ... 
  homepage: 'http://angular-ui.github.com',
  ... 
  version: '1.0.2',
  main: 'src/calendar.js',
  dependencies: {},
  ... 
}
```

- while the `package.json` file at
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/blob/1.0.2/package.json
shows a dependency of `fullcalendar:2.7.1`

```
{
  "name": "angular-ui-calendar",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  ... 
  "homepage": "http://angular-ui.github.com",
  "main": "src/calendar.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "fullcalendar": "~2.7.1"
  },
  ... 
}
```

---

**Questions:**

- why is there a difference for the *same* tagged version between `npm info` & github ?
- is there any way to tell NPM to update its (stored ?) package info  ?

---

**Notes:**
- I've run `npm cache clear` prior to remove any npm data that might be stored locally